# How to rotate the building with its axis in the center of the building?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I made a tool that can change the position of the building and its rotation.
When I change the position of the building and continue to change the rotation, the position back to the way it was.
Second question, can I rotate the building based on center axis ?.
Here is the code:

```
     // position 
     this.viewer.model.setPlacementTransform(
      new THREE.Matrix4().setPosition({
        x: this.valueX,
        y: this.valueY,
        z: this.valueZ,
      })
    );

   //rotation
   this.viewer.model.setPlacementTransform(
      new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(angleRadian)
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

The `setPlacementTransform` doesn't *modify* the models transformation matrix, it *overwrites* it. So when you call `this.viewer.model.setPlacementTransform(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(angleRadian));`, you're basically overwriting any transformation matrix that was applied to the model before.

A solution to this would be to combine the rotation and translation into a single transformation matrix:

```js
const rotation = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(angleRadian);
const translation = new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(someX, someY, someZ);
this.viewer.model.setPlacementTransform(rotation.multiply(translation));
// or `this.viewer.model.setPlacementTransform(translation.multiply(rotation));` depending on the order you need
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. How about I used the current matrix4 model using `this.viewer.model.getPlacementTransform()`?. But after I multiply it with new translation or rotation nothing change.

Comment: I wouldn't assume that `getPlacementTransform()` gives me an instance of the matrix I can just modify as is. No matter how you obtain the input matrices for the multiplication, it's better to just set the new matrix using the `setPlacementTransform()` method.